# Implementing a nytimes-style "end of article suggestion slider"

Tags: jquery

I want to implement something like this on my site:

[image]

The slider should appear when the user scrolls to the end of an article

Is there a jQuery plugin that handles this? [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/#documentation) looks promising, but I was hoping someone had a more specific solution.

Comment: it would be nice to see it implemented as a jQuery plugin. Any name suggestions?

Comment: Yes. The guy who made this at NYT did it as a side project and hadnt gotten any props, despite its incredible success (there are companies that sell this as a feature now!). Name it after him: Tahir Khan. KhanSlider?

Answer (score 3):

no need for a plugin:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      documentHeight = $(document).height(),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

if (windowHeight + scroll + 200 > documentHeight ) {
     // show the link bar
  }
});

This will show the link bar when you get within 200 pixels of the bottom.  `windowHeight` will hold the height of the visible portion of the screen, `documentHeight` will hold the total height of the page, including what you can and can't see, and `scroll` will hold how far down from the top of the document you have scrolled (it starts at 0).

Hope this helps :)